# Laravel- 'auth' middleware not work

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

I use Laravel 5.6.33. I would like the user can have an access to the 'dashboard' page only when he/she has signed In/Up. When I use the 'guest' middleware, the user can't access the page at all and when I use the 'auth' middleware, the user always have an access to the page. What shall I do?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
        'as' => 'dashboard',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
});
```

I have also added `$this->middleware('auth');` in the `getDashboard` function or in the constructor of the `UserController` but it doesn't work. What shall I do?

In the Kernel.php the `auth` address is as follows:

```
 'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Laravel 5.6` you don't need to wrap your routes with `web` middleware as long as you put them inside your `routes\web.php` file. Laravel makes this for you in the `RouteServiceProvider.php`.

For your purpose the `auth` middleware should work. Try this instead of what you have:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard'
  ]);
});
```

Comment: IDK what's wrong but in my laravel 5.7 `Route::group(['midddleware' => ['auth']], function () {` this was not working. And this `Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {` works.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do nothing.

- just add the following code.

```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function () {
    //you can create the list of the url or the resource here to block the unath users.
    Route::resource('brands', 'BrandController');
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
    });
```

Or use the construct function on the controller which you want to block.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

it will block all the function on that controller like index, create, store, update, delete. only auth can use those functions.